# Are there any rule-based named entity recognition libraries or projects available?

Tags: nlp

One that we looked at in the past is AeroText, but that does not look like it exists as its own project anymore.  I would think that it could be written in any language since we are interested in the output (the annotated entities), although it certainly would be a plus if it had a Java API that could be interfaced with.  Any level from free to purchase would be appreciated.

Just a note on the use, we will be using it as a supplemental annotator.  It will not be our main source of named entities generated.  So, yes, I am asking for **rule-based** suggestions only.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  [deid software package](https://www.physionet.org/physiotools/deid/) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20170522164106/https://www.physionet.org/physiotools/deid/)) provided with PhysioNet/mimic.

- rule-based
- free and open source (written in perl)
- the named entities are   [protected health information (PHI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protected_health_information)

Answer (score 0):

The question is 3 years old, but here is another answer:

What about [Spacy](https://spacy.io/usage/rule-based-matching#models-rules)?

- written in Python
- free
- no Java API , AFAIK

> Rule-based matching.  Find phrases and tokens, and match entities